# xCode / Objective-C Anatomy Analogies - Help a Noob Get It

Tags: objective-c, xcode, oop, delegates

OK so I'm trying to get started with Xcode and I have some experience with OOP in general but mostly I'm used to scripting. Anyhoo, I'm trying to get a handle on some concepts in objective C and xcode and I'm having some problems putting everything together.

For starters, I'm having trouble understanding what delegates and protocols do. I think it would be useful if someone could explain this with a simple analogy of a postman, or a teacher, or a factory or something. I don't understand the difference between a method in a delegate and a regular class methods.

Say I have a Class Postman. Now postman has methods sortMail() and deleteMail(). What's an example of a delegate method. And if a delegate is used, where is the data returned? Inside the delegate? Do I have to instantiate the delegate and then read results from it or does the delegate kinda give the results back to the calling object? Where do protocols come in...

Simple examples please :) Baby steps.

Comment: What kind of literature did you read on the topic so far?

Comment: I have an ios5 app development book. I guess I should probably buy an intro xcode book too.

Comment: Delegates and Protocols are not related to Xcode, but to Objective C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocols and Delegates go together frequently.  It helps to understand what a protocol is first.

**Protocol**

A protocol is a way of having a class promise to implement a standard set of methods.

Example: A certified electrician has a certain set of skills that all certified electricians will have.  If you need someone to do something that a certified electrician is certified to do, then any certified electrician should be able to do it (in theory at least).

**Delegate**

Now a delegate is an object that has been given a responsibility to fulfill certain requirements.  One object can be given the responsibility of fulfilling a need of another object.

Example: When building a house, the house needs to have wires run etc.  This responsibility has been given to a certified electrician, and we know he can do it because he's certified (i.e. implements a certain protocol).

**Putting it all together in a Cocoa context:**

A `UITableView` needs cells supplied so it can display them. To supply the cells, a class will need to be created (or at least specified) which implements the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.  That guarantees that the class does the needed things to supply the `UITableView` with the needed cells.

So the `UITableView` *delegates* the responsibility of providing the cells to a certain class object which implements the *protocol* which guarantees that the object knows how to supply the needed cells.

[Example](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/)

Comment: Perfect! I needed a real world example. Now I just have to figure out how to apply it! Thanks!

Comment: Example here: http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/introduction-to-table-view/

Comment: Actually, classes that implement a protocol make no promise to implement methods, especially if they are designated `@optional`.

Comment: That is true, however, I was trying to explain it in a non-confusing fashion.  Frequently technical details confuse the explanation.  I would argue that a protocol is a *promise* (apart from @optional of course) not a *guarantee*. Only the interface is available (unless you own the class), so you can't tell if the class does or does not implement the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

A delegate is an object that handles particular functionality for another object - as in "Object A delegates certain functionality to object B".

For instance, you may use an instance of Apple's class `NSURLConnection` to make a request for a web service, but Apple's code obviously won't know what to do with the data it downloads, so you provide a delegate object to handle that functionality.  `NSURLConnection` then delegates that functionality to your object by passing it messages when it needs to do something like handle the data it downloads.

Another example is a table view.  Apple have written a lot of code to display table views and handle interactions with them, but it doesn't know what data you want to display or what needs to be done with that data when somebody interacts with it.  So you can provide delegate objects for these things.  When a table view needs to know what data to display, it asks your delegate to fetch the data for it.  When the user selects an item, it asks your delegate to handle it.

A protocol is simply a way of describing what messages the delegate is supposed to understand.  There can be informal protocols, where it's just described in the documentation, and formal protocols, which are defined in a header file.